# How to check if POST form data is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, nancy

I am writing a CRUD web api using Nancy on .NET. While trying to do some server side validation, I am having difficulties blocking a form with empty values written on the database.

Here is my Controller/Module:

```
 public dynamic NEW_POST(dynamic parameters)
        {
            //Binds model to form
            var post = this.Bind<Post>();
            if (post.Title.Length == 0 && post.Content.Length == 0)
            {
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }

            else
            {
                _post.Create(post);
                return Response.AsRedirect("/");
            }

        }
```

I have also tried checking if the model == null.

Empty values still go through the controller and make it to the database. 
Any tips would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the common way to check it:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["name"]))
```

The post data is contained in the *Form* collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually would do this and check the data that is being `posted` is null (like you said?). For example:

```
public class CustomerModule : NancyModule
{
    public CustomerModule()
    {
        this.Post["api/customers"] = args => this.AddCustomer();
    }

    private Negotiator AddCustomer()
    {
        var customer = this.Bind<Customer>();

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return this.Negotiate.WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return this.Negotiate.WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

This works a treat when I launch the app locally. For full source code you can have a look at [here](https://github.com/OnamChilwan/NancyFx-Concept).